# Параметры изображения

Tags: php

Вывод коталога с миниатюрами изображений выглядит так:

```
        $img = "images/catalog/thumb/".($models[$mod_id]['filesmall']!=""?$models[$mod_id]['filesmall']:"none.jpg");
```

как к этому изображению применить параметр при выводе border=\"0\" width=\"150px\" height=\"200px\" ????

Answer (score 1):

создай отдельный css класс и добавляй его. хотя так как ты делаешь, делать не есть хорошо. Нужно через РНР обрезать изображения

Comment: Задача не обрезать изображение, а уменьшить его размер на выходе

Comment: @Дмитрий Гончаров, я думаю, что @mountpoint хотел сказать, что лучше уменьшить/обрезать или что-либо еще на входе, а не на выходе. Т.е. Уменьшенная превьюшка, заранее подготовленная для предпросмотра.

Comment: @Дмитрий Гончаров, может немного не так выразился. Вам нужно еще на серверной стороне уменьшить изображение, а не на стороне клиента. На стороне клиента - это не по феншую и Гугл при индексации сайта отметит это как ошибку.